# Thread.join() not behaving as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm pretty new to Multithreading in java but am totally stumped about why this isn't behaving as I want it to.

I have a Producer-Consumer wherein I have

```
    private void produceConsume() {
        try {
           Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
               try {
                produce();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               } finally {
                completedProduce = true;
               }
             }

             private void produce() throws InterruptedException {
               synchronized (this) {

                 while (queue.size() == capacity) {
                    wait();
                 }

                 try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                   queue.add("hello");
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                   LOG.error("Error doing stream stuff: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                 }
                 notify();
               }
            }
          });
          producer.start();

          List<Thread> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

          for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++) {

          Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 try {
                   consume();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }

             private void consume() throws InterruptedException {
                while (queue.size() > 0 || !completedProduce) {
                   synchronized (this) {
                       while (queue.size() == 0 && !completedProduce) {
                          wait();
                       }
                       String s = queue.poll();
                       System.out.println(s);
                }
                notify();
              }
            }
          }
        });
        consumer.start();
        consumers.add(consumer);
      }

      for (Thread t : consumers) {
            t.join();
      }
      producer.join();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("InterruptedException e: " + e.getMessage(), e);
   } finally {
        LOG.info("We are done with this file!");
   }
}
```

Now, I've noticed that all functionality changes based on where I put my `producer.join()` statement. For example, if I put `producer.join()` right after `producer.start()` then everything works - but the number of threads has no impact on runtime. This makes sense as I'm slowed down drastically by how long it takes to produce and so the longest task wins out.

However, if I put `producer.join()` where it is in the example provided (I do the join when I do the join for the consumers) then everything just stops running before the producer actually finishes. As in, the program stalls after the first thing is consumed, waiting for something, but the thread never dies.

How do I make it so that things run correctly and nothing stalls waiting for another process to finish?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's impossible to explain anything without knowing what the treads do. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly being caused by this: `// actual implementation omitted`

Comment: In multithreaded application, it is hard to predict, how threads will cooperate between and which one will finish first, as it depends on implementation.
If you put producer.join right after producer.start, then consumer threads will not be created until producer thread finishes.
What actually is your final goal ?

Comment: @JBNizet  Sorry about that. I edited to include implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @Marvin I would like both of them to be running concurrently in a good producer-consumer model. But, for some reason when I try to set that up (like the code I have posted) it stalls after the first consuming takes place.

Comment: Don't see a declaration for `completedProduce`, which means it's likely a single variable that's being shared by both producers and consumers.  Sharing unsafe variables can easily lead to this sort of situation - especially since you're using it as a conditional for thread coordination.  In general you want to make thread coordination code as simple as possible.  Using two variables (`completedProduce` and `queue.size()`) can easily lead to insane states.  That all being said, this question is still not an [mcve] so it's pretty much impossible to tell what the real issue is.

Comment: But, there's only one producer. So, it's only being changed once by one thread, right? Shouldn't that account for any volatility? Or, am I totally misunderstanding the situation?

Comment: It could be as simple as this.  A piece of unsynchronized code like this: `queue.size() > 0 || !completedProduce` uses two separate conditions.  Unfortunately, two consumer threads each update one of those conditions at the same time leading to an illogical state that causes other consumers to wait forever.  Since your program waits for all threads to complete, you're stuck.  AGAIN, it's impossible to be sure, the code you posted is not an [mcve]

Comment: Pretty sure if you get an IOException when `queue.size()` is zero you're hosed.  (Probably not causing your current issue)

Comment: Given that each `Runnable` uses `synchronized`, `wait()` and `notify()` on itself, it doesn't seem like there's much actual synchronization going on between the threads...

Comment: @Tibrogargan I successfully was able to make a toy example with both conditionals - that all it did was read and write a string. However, I can't seem to replicate the success in my actual code. Even when I take out one of the conditionals I still get stalled.

Comment: Re, "I would like both of them to be running concurrently..."  If so, then why does your consumer wait until the producer is finished (`while(...&& !completedProduce) { wait(); }`) before it prints anything?

Comment: @jameslarge It's not waiting until the producer is finished. It's waiting until stuff is in the queue - but we need some flag so that this isn't an infinite loop and so we know to stop waiting once the producer is done.

Comment: Your producer only sets `completedProduce` in one place:  just before the producer thread's `run()` method returns.

Comment: The producer/consumer pattern is actually quite simple.  Your code is complicating it unnecessarily.  It goes something like this: `producer: do { createProduct(); synchronized(productSignal) { putProductOnQueue(); notify() } until(workComplete)` and `consumer: while(notDone) { wait(); synchronized(productSignal) { getProductFromQueue } consumeProduct(); }`.   The only thing you might want to do is add a guard in the producer on the queue being full and have a separate signal so consumers can tell the producer when they have removed something.  Not an issue when the work is finite.

Comment: @LivingRobot For a start, you can use System.in.read() to wait, while threads are executing, no need to join(). When you will achieve threads doing what you want, then you can add some listener-notifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up finding out that the issue was in the `wait()` going on for the consumer. It turned out that it was waiting and nothing was in fact waking it up because notify `notify()` from the producer wasn't getting to it. I simply replaced the `wait()` with a `Thread.sleep(1000)` and that did the trick. Thanks again!